# Necessity of curly braces while importing modules

Tags: node.js

I come across two different ways of importing modules in Node.js. When do we need to use curly braces to import the modules?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose.js');
```

In ES6, we can import the named exports using curly braces as follows:

```
import {mongoose} from './db/mongoose.js'
```

Is the same rule applicable for importing using `require` as well?

Comment: its an es6 specification and its called [object destruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and it works with import not require.

Comment: @Miqe Not really, "destruction" since you're not destroying, but object destructuring..

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanks for the heads up its definitely object destructuring